# How to create two different contact forms in one page PHP

Tags: php, forms, email

I am trying to make to different contact forms in PHP but one of them is currently working, the other one is not. 
This is the code I am using:

```
require 'php/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'php/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'php/class.smtp.php';

/*Send message CONTACT FORM*/
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";

$name = $_POST['txtName'];
$message = $_POST['txtMessage'];
$email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$emailC = $_POST['txtEmailC'];

$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Name = $name;
$mail->Subject = $email; 
$mail->Body = 'Name: ' .$name .'    Message: ' .$message . '    Email: '       .$email;
$mail->AddAddress("email@domain.com");

 if (isset($_POST['btnSend'])) 
 {
 if($email !== $emailC)
 {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Emails are not matching");</script>';
 }
 else
 {
     if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data has been submitted to ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '");</script>';
            header("Refresh:0");   
        }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your message was sent correctly!");</script>';
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
 }
}

 $request = new PHPMailer();
 $request->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
 $request->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
 $request->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
 $request->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 $request->Port = 587;
 $request->IsHTML(true);
 $request->Username = "email@gmail.com";
 $request->Password = "password";


 //Set of the variables
 $fn = $_POST['txtFirstName']; 
 $ln = $_POST['txtLastname'];
 $pn = $_POST['txtPhoneNumber'];
 $em = $_POST['txtEmail']; 
 $cm = $_POST['txtCompany'];
 $tt = $_POST['txtTitle'];
 $sd = $_POST['slDemo'];

 $request->SetFrom("email@gmail.com");
 $request->Name = $fn + " " + $ln;
 $request->Subject = "Demo Request: " + $sd;  
 $request->Body = 'Requester Name: ' .$fn .'    Requester Lastname: ' .$ln .   '    Requester #Number: ' .$pn .   'Requester Email: ' .$em . 'Requester         Company: ' .$cm . 'Requester title: ' .$tt . 'Requester DEMO: ' .$sd;
 $request->AddAddress("email@domain.com");


 try
 {
 if (isset($_POST['btnRequest'])) 
 {
    if(!$request->Send())
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data has been submitted to ' . $request->ErrorInfo . '");</script>';
        //header("Refresh:0");   
        echo 'Data was submitted';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your message was sent correctly!");</script>';
        //header("Refresh:0");
        echo 'Your message was snet';
    }
  } 
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("There was an error: ! ' + $ex-  >getMessage() +'");</script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("There was an error: !");</script>';
header("Refresh:0");
}
```

Also these are the HTML code for both:

```
<form method="post" role="form">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h4>Request Demo Form</h4>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <input id="txtFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" name="rqFirstname" required />
                            <input style="margin-top: 2%;" id="txtLastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" name="rqLastname" required/>
                            <input style="margin-top: 2%;" id="txtPhoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" name="rqPhone" required />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" name="rqPEmail" required />
                            <input style="margin-top: 2%;" id="txtCompany" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" name="rqCompany" required/>
                            <input style="margin-top: 2%;" id="txtTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Title" name="rqTitle" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h4>Demo</h4>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <select name="demoSelection" id="slDemo" style="margin-top: 2%;" class="form-control">
                                    <option class="text-muted">-- Choose your demo --</option>
                                    <option value="Commisions">Commisions</option>
                                    <option value="CPQ">CPQ</option>
                                    <option value="ImprovedApps">ImprovedApps</option>
                                    <option value="MarketingAutomation">Marketing Automation</option>
                                    <option value="DataCleansing">Data Cleansing</option>
                                    <option value="SalesCoachihg">Sales Coaching & Learning Management</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div style="margin-top: 2%;" class="footer pull-right">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Request" id="btnRequest" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </form>
```

And this is the 2nd form

```
<form method="post" role="form">
            <div class="well well-sm"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span> Required Field</small></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="txtName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="InputEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" id="txt" name="txtEmailC" placeholder="Confirm your Email" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <textarea id="InputMessage" class="form-control input-sm" name="txtMessage" placeholder="Your message here..." rows="5" required></textarea>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Remember to fill correctly every field before sending you message." type="submit" name="btnSend" id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i> Submit</button>
        </form>
```

What I am trying to do is create a contact form and request contact, two different forms. Is there any other better way to do this?
Please can someone tells me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can have two forms, just make sure the submits have different names. Check the name and use that to determine which PHP to run.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Both contain this: ** <form method="post" role="form"> **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line uses `id="btnRequest"` but it should be `name="btnRequest"` in order to have php receive it as a form variable and be able to use it in `$_POST['btnRequest']`,

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Request" id="btnRequest" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see your HTML code, so just make sure you do this:

```
<form>1st Form</form>
<form>2nd Form</form>
```

Generally when my forms aren't behaving properly it's because the 1st form isn't properly closed ahead of time. It's a pretty common mistake. You can have the same field names and it won't matter as long as both forms are completely separate like above.

Comment: I pasted the HTML code. I also did that but it's not working.